# NetLogo check if turtles are on same coordinates

Tags: netlogo, turtle-graphics, coordinate

I have two turtle breeds who populate each sides of the window and then only move round in there own side.

The problem I am having is that I want to constantly check to see if one singular instance of a turtle from each breed are both on the same y coordinate. And if this returns true i want both of those turtles to stop, but for all other turtles from each breed to carry on moving. I know you can identify a turtle by there unique ID but i don't know how to use this and how to use the correct syntax.

The best way to describe this in pseudo code would be

```
ask turtles [
    if breed1 turtle ycor = breed2 turtle ycor
        [ stop breed1 turtle and breed2 turtle ] ]
```

*UPDATE*
Tried getting the code to work but still nothing happening. Not sure if it is the way the procedure is wrote or the number I have chosen for the threshold.

```
to move-turtles
 ask turtles [
if not any? turtles with [ breed != [ breed ] of myself and abs (ycor - [ycor] of myself) < 1 ]
[
ask redteam with [pcolor = green - 3] [
right random 360
forward 1
]
ask redteam with [pcolor != green - 3] [ 
back 1
]
ask blueteam with [pcolor = green - 2] [
right random 360
forward 1
]
ask blueteam with [pcolor != green - 2] [ 
back 1
]]
]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that "same coordinate" is actually somewhat ambiguous. If one turtles `ycor` is `5.0000001` and another's is `5.0000000`, are they at the same coordinate? Because of this, you should check to see if their coordinates are within a certain amount of each other.

Also, the best way to stop moving is to simply not move. So, here is a possible `go` procedure that would do what you want:

```
to go
  ask turtles [
    if not any? turtles with [ breed != [ breed ] of myself and abs (ycor - [ ycor ] of myself) < threshold ] [
      move ;; replace with your move procedure or code
    ]
  ]
end
```

Here, each turtle checks to see if there are any turtles of a different breed who's `ycor` is within `threshold` of their own `ycor`. If there are not, then it moves. Otherwise, it does nothing.

The [`myself`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#myself) stuff is the most confusing part here, so I recommend reading the docs.

Comment: Note that if the turtles jump from patch center to patch center (like checkers or chess), the issue about slight differences in coordinates can't arise.

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware that's how coordinates worked. My turtles are using the "person" as there shape and have a set size of 1.5. I guess what I want to consider to be the same "y coordinate". So in your example of 5.0000000 and 5.0000001 being the same, I would rather my turtles check if they are both simply on the 5 y coordinate, so rounding up or down the whole number.

Comment: Have them compare `pycor` then, instead of `ycor`. (A turtle has direct access to the variables of the patch it is standing on, including `pycor`.)

Comment: Tried putting that code you gave into my program but not getting it to work at all. I've added the procedure where i am using it into the OP if you wouldn't mind taking a look. Thanks